# Как запретить активировать JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing

Хочу написать многооконный пользовательский интерфейс. Использую `JDesktopPane`, добавляю на него несколько `JInternalFrame`. Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Фрейм №1 - это тоже `JInternalFrame`, просто я убрал у него рамки. Проблема в том, что если сейчас щелкнуть по Фрейм №1, он станет активным, выйдет на передний план, перекроет Фрейм №2 и Фрейм №3 и до них уже нельзя будет никак добраться.
Как можно запретить активировать Фрейм №1?

вот так я создаю фреймы:

```
protected void createFrame() {
    MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true); //necessary as of 1.3
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
}
```

Для Фрейм №1 код немного другой, там я занимаюсь оформлением. Но думаю эти детали здесь не имеют значения.

А это класс MyInternalFrame:

```
public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame{

 static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("Document #" + (++openFrameCount), 
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

        //...Create the GUI and put it in the window...

        //...Then set the window size or call pack...
        setSize(300,300);

        //Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
    }

}
```

Так же приведу метод, в котором создается `JFrame`:

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    int inset = 50;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setBounds(inset, inset, screenSize.width - inset * 2,
            screenSize.height - inset * 2);
    desktop = new JDesktopPane(); // a specialized layered pane 
    createfirstFrame();
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    pan.add(new JTextField(12));
    desktop.add(pan);
    frame.getContentPane().add(desktop);
    frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
    desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @LEQADA, добавил свой код, в котором создаю JInternalFrame-ы.

Comment: @LEQADA, может я вообще хочу невозможного от JInternalFrame? И есть другой способ реализовать нужное мне поведение? Поделитесь пожалуйста, если есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

Вариант 1: запрет установки `selected` в `true`. Фрейм не может быть выбран, в качестве активного, поэтому не перемещается наверх. Недостатки: не подсвечивается заголовок, если фрейм активен, логика использует исключения.

```
    backFrame.addVetoableChangeListener( new VetoableChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
            if (  JInternalFrame.IS_SELECTED_PROPERTY.equals( evt.getPropertyName() ) && Boolean.TRUE.equals( evt.getNewValue() ) ) {
                throw new PropertyVetoException( "you shall not pass!", evt );
            }
        }
    });
```

Вариант 2: после активации фрейма, отправляем его на дно. Недостатки: теоретически это может быть заметно.

```
    backFrame.addInternalFrameListener( new InternalFrameAdapter () {
        @Override
        public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            desktop.moveToBack( e.getInternalFrame() );             
        }
    });
```

Еще можно переопределить `JDesktopPane.moveToFront` и запретить подъем конкретного окна.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу сказать огромное спасибо zRrr! Ваш ответ мне очень помог. Посмею немного дополнить ваш ответ - приведу свою реализацию JDesktopPane.moveToFront. Может кому-нибудь пригодится.
Тот JInternalFrame, который мне нужно оставлять внизу, я реализовал в отдельном классе. Вот его код:

```
public class MyInternalFrame2 extends JInternalFrame {

public MyInternalFrame2() {
    setVisible(true);// necessary as of 1.3
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    pan.add(new JLabel("Фрейм №1"));
    pan.add(new JTextField(12));
    add(pan);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI) this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
    setBorder(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(50, 50, 1000, 500);

}
```

}

Это я сделал для того что бы в методе JDesktopPane.moveToFront можно было отличить этот особенный frame по типу и обработать соответствующим образом. Вот моя реализация этого метода:

```
public class MyJDesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

@Override
public void moveToFront(Component c){
    if(c instanceof MyInternalFrame2){
        setPosition(c, -1);
    }
    else{
        setPosition(c, 0);
    }
}
```

}

В заключение хочу сказать, что оставшиеся 2 варианта, которые привел zRrr так же отлично работают.

Comment: @zRrr, единственный вопрос возник по второму варианту. Долго пытался с ним разобраться, но так до конца и не понял код. Мы вешаем слушателя, который задает неразрешенные событие. Дальше мы определяем что неразрешенным событием будет выбор того JInternalFrame, на который мы вешаем слушателя. Это вроде понятно (поправьте пожалуйста, если я ошибаюсь). Но вот как так получается, что дальше мы выбрасываем исключение, которое нигде не ловится, но при этом и программа не падает? Это не понятно. Предположу, что выбросом исключения мы как бы подавляем событие. Поэтому JInternalFrame и не активируется?

Comment: Исключение обрабатывают те, кто вызывает `setSelected`, как вы в примере кода из вопроса, или слушатель событий мыши. Выброс исключения прекращает выполнение `setSelected`, поэтому код присвоения свойству нового значения и рассылки событий не сработатывет.